# How do you import a file from a package when the file itself has imports?

Tags: python, import, structure, project

The structure of my project is
Package
--Subpackage1
---file1
---file2
--Subpackage2
---file3

Inside file1 I imported a class from file2 and it works using from file2 import class, Then from file 3 I used sys.path.append('..') and imported file1 which seems to work. However, the import into file1 from file2 gives an error. How do I get the imports to work both when I just run file 1 and when I import code from file1 into file3?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sys.path.append('../Subpackage1')`?

Comment: I used sys.path.append('..') and then did import subpackage1.file1, which I think is the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all the directories with dependencies in `sys.path`.

Based on the comment, if you wish to add the root directory, you would have to add the sub-directory as well

```
sys.path.append('..')
sys.path.append('../Subpackage1')
import Subpackage1.file1
```

Or, you could just add the sub-directory and import directly

```
sys.path.append('../Subpackage1')
import file1
```